# Beautifulsoup can't find tag by text

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Beautifulsoup suddenly can't find a tag by its text.

I have a html in which this tag appears:

```
<span class="date">Telefon: <b>+421 902 808 344</b></span>
```

BS4 can't find this tag:

```
telephone = soup.find('span',{'text':re.compile('.*Telefon.*')})
print telephone

>>> None
```

I've tried many ways like

`find('span',text='Telefon: ')` or 
`find('span', text=re.compile('Telefon: .*')`

But nothing works. I've tried already change `html.parser` to `lxml`.

What may be wrong?

Comment: Are you able to find the text by searching for the `span` with the class of `date`?

Comment: @AnthonyForloney Yes, I'm :) It's weird. Here is the output for findAll/span/class=date: [<span class="date">Kontaktní osoba: <b>Jozef</b></span>, <span class="date">Ulice, č.p.: <b>M.M 3</b></span>, <span class="date">Město: <b>Bratis</b></span>, <span class="date">Okres: <b>Bratis</b></span>, <span class="date">Kraj: <b>Bratisl</b></span>, <span class="date">PSČ: <b>84147</b></span>, <span class="date">Telefon: <b>+4205545575</b></span>, <span class="date">E-mail: <b><a href="mailto:smid@gm>smid@gm</a></b></span>] So it is definitely considered as a Tag

Comment: what about `print(soup.find('span',{"class":"date"}))`?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham It returns the first span meeting this conditions. It works so I don't know what's the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BeautifulSoup regards the string `Telefon:` as being a [`bs4.element.NavigableString`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring) inside the `span` tag. So you could find it with

```
import bs4
import re

soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup('<span class="date">Telefon: <b>+421 902 808 344</b></span>')
for span in soup.find_all('span', {'class':"date"}):
    if span.find(text=re.compile('Telefon:')):
        for text in span.stripped_strings:
            print(text)
# Telefon:
# +421 902 808 344
```

Or, you could use lxml directly:

```
import lxml.html as LH

root = LH.fromstring('<span class="date">Telefon: <b>+421 902 808 344</b></span>')

for span in root.xpath('//span[@class="date" and contains(text(), "Telefon:")]'):
    print(span.text_content())
    # Telefon: +421 902 808 344
```